# Counting the number of possible sequences increasing by no more than one

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

> Count the number of sequences of integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ such that
> $$
> a_1 = 0 
> \quad\text{and}\quad 
> 0 \leq a_{i+1} \leq a_i + 1 
> \quad\text{for}\quad
> 1 \leq i < n.
> $$

At first, I was looking for a connection with Catalan numbers, since this task is from this topic. But I didn't find it. And then I tried to find some recurrence relation for it to make a generating function and I failed at that as well. Help me please

Comment: Do you have a guess for what the formula for $a_n$ is? You should be able to guess, because it is a famous sequence. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4867237/edit) your question to include your guess, and to say what problems you run into when you try to prove your guess.

Comment: For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with 
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to answer the question.

Comment: Find the first few $a_i$ and then search for it on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) if needed.

Comment: The answer is the $n$th Catalan number indeed. Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#:~:text=is%20the%20number%20of%20length) will help.

Comment: @MikeEarnest , it was useful tip. Thank you!

Comment: @DS , it confirmed mu assumptions, thank you too

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer , I didn't know about this website before, thank you

Comment: @Email That website is a gold mine. If you want to find a general sequence, find the first few terms and search it. So convenient!